# attandance query to show in and out

Tags: php, mysql

Attandance query to show in and out but date of end then next day start from out. My table data is:

```
attendance_id student_id get_id attendance_date attendancetime create_user create_datetime     edit_user edit_datetime
            1          8      0 2016-08-02      12:10:01                 0 0000-00-00 00:00:00         0 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
            2          8      0 2016-08-02      00:00:00                 0 0000-00-00 00:00:00         0 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            3          8      0 2016-08-02      14:00 00                 0 2016-08-08 05:00:00         0 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            5          8      0 2016-08-06      06:00:00                 0 2016-08-08 05:00:00         0 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            6          8      0 2016-08-06      13:00:00                 0 2016-08-08 05:00:00         0 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
            7          8      0 2016-08-10      06:00:00                 1 2016-08-11 01:58:00         1 2016-08-11 01:58:00 
            8          8      0 2016-08-10      12:00:00                 1 2016-08-11 01:58:00         1 2016-08-11 01:58:00
```

My code is:

```
$dategroup_str = "SELECT  b.all_date,hostel_attendance.attendancetime,hostel_attendance.attendance_date FROM 
                            (SELECT * FROM 
                            (SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) all_date FROM 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) 
                            AS d ".$where_clause." ) AS b
                            LEFT JOIN hostel_attendance ON b.all_date = hostel_attendance.attendance_date 
                            AND  hostel_attendance.student_id='$show_student_id' order BY b.all_date";
    echo $dategroup_str;
    $dategroup_sql = $mysqli->query($dategroup_str);
    $dategroup_count = $dategroup_sql->num_rows;
    $i=1;
    $j=0;
    while($dategroup_sel = $dategroup_sql->fetch_row())
    { 
        if($i%2 != 0){?>
        <tr>
            <td class="center" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo $dategroup_sel[0];?></td>

            <td class="center" style="text-transform:capitalize;">
            <?php if($dategroup_sel[1]!=''){echo $dategroup_sel[1];}else{echo "-";}?>
            </td>
            <?php }elseif($i%2 == 0){?>
            <td class="center" style="text-transform:capitalize;">
            <?php if($dategroup_sel[1]!=''){echo $dategroup_sel[1];}else{echo "-";}?>
            </td>
         </tr>
            <?php }
        $i++; } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Output is
[image]
my output show this type

Comment: Please edit your question, make the code more readable (perhaps the SQL alone) , and add some information regarding the output you want to achieve.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The sample output - is that how you want it to be, or how it's currently working? It would help to have both versions. You haven't explained what the problem is. You've just shown some code and some output without saying what's wrong.

Comment: Given that this is tagged with PHP, I would use that to solve the presentation issue (i.e. to display missing dates)

Answer (score 0):

$datearr_str = "SELECT  b.all_date,hostel_attendance.attendancetime FROM 
                            (SELECT * FROM 
                            (SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) all_date FROM 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) 
                            AS d ".$where_clause." ) AS b
                            LEFT JOIN hostel_attendance ON b.all_date = hostel_attendance.attendance_date 
                            AND  hostel_attendance.student_id='$show_student_id' order BY b.all_date,hostel_attendance.attendancetime";
        //echo $datearr_str;
        $datearr_sql = $mysqli->query($datearr_str);
        $datearr_count = $datearr_sql->num_rows;
        $datestr = "";
        $timestr = "";
        while($datearr_sel = $datearr_sql->fetch_row())
        {
            if($datestr == ""){ $datestr = $datearr_sel[0];}else{ $datestr = $datestr.",".$datearr_sel[0];}
            if($timestr == ""){ $timestr = $datearr_sel[1];}else{ $timestr = $timestr.",".$datearr_sel[1];}
        }
        $datearr = explode(",",$datestr);
        $timearr = explode(",",$timestr);
        //print_r($timearr);
        $dtgp_str = "SELECT  b.all_date,hostel_attendance.attendancetime,hostel_attendance.attendance_id FROM 
                            (SELECT * FROM 
                            (SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) all_date FROM 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) 
                            AS d ".$where_clause." ) AS b
                            LEFT JOIN hostel_attendance ON b.all_date = hostel_attendance.attendance_date 
                            AND  hostel_attendance.student_id='$show_student_id' order BY b.all_date,hostel_attendance.attendancetime";
        //echo $dtgp_str;
        $dtgp_sql = $mysqli->query($dtgp_str);
        $dtgp_count = $dtgp_sql->num_rows;
        $j=1;
        $k=1;
        $l=1;
        //print_r($timearr);

```
    while($dtgp_sel = $dtgp_sql->fetch_row())
    { 
        $all_date  = $dtgp_sel[0];
        $next_date = $datearr[$l];
        //echo $timearr[$k];
        //echo "k- ".$k;
        if($timearr[$k] !=""){$one_time_before_time = $timearr[$k];}else{$one_time_before_time = '551';}
        if($j !=$l){
            ?>          
                <tr>
                    <td class="center" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo $all_date;?></td>

                    <td class="center" style="text-transform:capitalize;">
                    <?php if($dtgp_sel[1]!=''){echo $dtgp_sel[1]; }else{echo "-";}?>
                    </td>


                    <?php //echo $all_date . "/". $next_date;
                    if(strtotime($all_date)==strtotime($next_date))
                    { ?>
                        <td class="center" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php  echo $one_time_before_time; ?></td> 

                    <?php $i=2; $k=$k+$i;}
                     else
                        {?>
                            <td class="center" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php  echo "-" ; ?></td> 
                        <?php $i=1;$k=$k+$i;  } ?>

                 </tr>
                    <?php

            //echo " j-".$j." i-".$i." l-".$l."<br>";   
         $j=$j+$i; }$l++; } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
                            </div>
```